# Google checkout reporting API - How to use it with C#?

Tags: c#, api, reporting, google-checkout

Today I stumbled upon the Google Checkout Reporting API (see link below). Although I read through the whole page I didn't quite understand how to implement this one (e.g. using C#). Sadly I couldn't find any examples or tutorials either.
Has anyone successfully used this API? Can anyone give me a little starting help?

Thanks!

[Google checkout reporting API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API.html)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but it looks promising
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html

Comment: I quickly browsed through that page. It seems to be focused on some other things and is based on several Google DLLs I can't use...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google Checkout .NET library and sample code.

It has code samples you can re-use to implement a .NET framework for the Reporting API (e.g. HTTP requests, XML parsing, HTTP Basic Authentication, etc):

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html